# Pagination for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have created datatable view using UICollectionView.

This is the code:

```
class PanelViewController: UIViewController{

var TableHeaderArray = NSMutableArray()
var TableDataArray = NSMutableArray()
var NumberOfRows = Int()   
var UlockDataArray = NSMutableArray()
let dataSource = DataSource()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource.populateData()

    let noOfRows = dataSource.NumberOfRows
    self.NumberOfRows = noOfRows + 1

    self.UlockDataArray = dataSource.DUDataArray
    self.TableDataArray = dataSource.DTableDataArray   


    let layout: CustomCollectionViewLayout = CustomCollectionViewLayout()

    DataTableCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.TableVu.bounds.width, height:self.TableVu.bounds.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    DataTableCollectionView.dataSource = self
    DataTableCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.DataTableCollectionView .registerNib(UINib(nibName: "FixedCellIdentifier", bundle: nil), 
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FixedCellIdentifier)
    self.DataTableCollectionView .registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DynamoCellIdentifier", bundle: nil),
     forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DynamoCellIdentifier)

    self.TableVu.addSubview(DataTableCollectionView)        
    self.view.addSubview(TableVu)

}
```

}

```
extension PanelViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{        
        return self.NumberOfRows
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {     
    return dataSource.TableHeaders.count        
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // My Code to Create Cells using data from TableHeaderArray, TableDataArray and UlockDataArray

}


func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
   let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
   var returnUmidData = NSMutableArray()
   var returnTableData = NSMutableArray()

   if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {   

        self.dataSource.populateData()

        returnUData = self.dataSource.DUDataArray
        returnTableData = self.dataSource.DTableDataArray


        let seconds = 5.0
        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

             self.NumberOfRows += returnTableData.count

             let mergetWorkoutData = NSMutableArray(array: self.UlockDataArray)
             mergetWorkoutData.addObjectsFromArray(returnUmidData as [AnyObject])

             self.UlockDataArray = mergetWorkoutData

             let mergetWorkoutTabelData = NSMutableArray(array: self.TableDataArray)
             mergetWorkoutTabelData.addObjectsFromArray(returnTableData as [AnyObject])

             self.TableDataArray = mergetWorkoutTabelData 

            self.DataTableCollectionView!.reloadData()

        })
   }
}
```

}

Initialy, I am displaying first 50 records. I need to implement pagination on vertical scroll.
Each time user reach to end of scroll, I want to make an API call to get the next 50 records.

But in doing so, I am getting an error

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:
 index 51 beyond bounds [0 .. 50]'"
```

I think somehow indexPath is not getting updated but unable to understand where and why or how to update it. Can you please advise?

Comment: I have seen the crash report it is due to the index beyond the bond. Like you are fetching the index that is not present in array. This is not an issue with memory.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use collectionView's willDisplayCell method, which is more manageable.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
               forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row + 1 == dataSource.count && dataSource.count < myPaginationUpperLimit {
        paginateMore()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

you can use the below UICollectionViewDelegate method:-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        {
            if NumberOfRows >= indexPath.row
            {
                // call API
                // add data to array
                // reload collectionview
                NumberOfRows == TableDataArray.count
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**for easy way to use Pagination you need to use willDisplay cell mathod**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if currentPage < totalPage && indexPath.item == array.count - 1 {
            currentPage += 1
            // pass currenPage number in API
            // add data to array
            // reload collectionview
        }
    }
```