# Way to limit collection view number of cells loaded at a time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have 200 items in the array and I am passing to the collection view While Running on the device it gets Crashed due to memory warning. Is there any way to limit cell to a row at index path according to scrolling.Due to downloading images it showing memory warning. if I skip the downloading part then it's not crashing.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell:ProductListCell? = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductListCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductListCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        let nib: NSArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProductListCell", owner: self, options: nil)! as NSArray
        cell = (nib.object(at: 0) as? ProductListCell)!
        cell?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        cell?.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale;
    }

        if let url = NSURL(string: ((self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].productPic)!)) {
            cell?.imgProduct.sd_setImage(with: url as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        }

    if let strProductName = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].ProductName {
        cell?.lblProductName.text = strProductName
    }

    cell?.lblProductDesc .text = ""

    if let strProductPrice = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].MRP {
        cell?.lblProductPrice.attributedText = Common().setPrice(Price:strProductPrice, StrikePrice1:(self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].discountprice)!)
    }

    if let strDiscount = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].DiscountPercentage {
        if strDiscount > 0 {
            cell?.btnDiscount.setTitle("\(strDiscount)% off", for: .normal)
        } else {
            cell?.btnDiscount.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    if let strRatingDesc = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].TotalRating_Reviews {
        cell?.lblRatingdesc.text = strRatingDesc
    }

    if let strRating = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].AvgRatingCount {
        cell?.lblRating.text = "\(strRating)"
    }

    if let intRating = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].AvgRatingCount {
        cell?.subViewRating.rating = intRating
    }

    if let strShopName = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].ShopName {
        cell?.lblShopName.text = strShopName
    }

    if let strDisctance = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].Distance {
        cell?.lblDistance.setTitle("\(strDisctance) km near by you", for: .normal)
    }

    if let strLandLineNo = self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].LandLineNumber {
        cell?.lblMobileNo.text = "\(strLandLineNo)"
    }

    cell?.btnAddToCompare.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.btnAddToCompare.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClickedAddToCompare(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell?.btnAddProduct.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.btnAddProduct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClickedAddProduct(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell?.btnCall.tag = indexPath.row
     cell?.btnCall.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.callCellactn(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell?.btnMap.tag = indexPath.row
     cell?.btnMap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.locationCellactn(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Please add the pagination concept and load 10 for page 1 and 20 for page 2 like that.

Comment: can u give me that concept link

Comment: Check this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374928/pagination-for-uicollectionview

Comment: can you share that download code and where you put it

Comment: @Maheshkumar there no right answer in that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have placed Collection View in ScrollView Thats why it is calling All 100 cells at a time. then i removed Scroll view then it is working Fine

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the number of cells is the issue. UICollectionView manages the collection of cells automatically, including disposing of off-screen cells.

I think it's more likely that you are experiencing memory leaks that prevent the cells from being actually deallocated when UICollectionView lets go of them. You have a lot of blocks in there that may be causing such memory leaks.

Comment: if I remove setting image for url then it is not crashing  if let url = NSURL(string: ((self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row].productPic)!)) {
            cell?.imgProduct.sd_setImage(with: url as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        }

Comment: @Abhiram before that line, add cell?.imgProduct.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad() and try

Answer (score 1):

You can use pagination concept to stop loading all the cell at a time. And it revoke the high memory usage of reusable cell.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495750/uitableview-pagination-bottom-refresh-to-load-new-data-in-swift) will elaborate to use of Pagination concept.

Comment: is there any way for calling cell for item at index after scrolling

Comment: reusing cells is implemented exactly for that purposes.. no more cells than are needed to be displayed are in fact instantiated - how would pagination help?

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly reusing the cell that is the reason for memory warning
Remove this `

```
if (cell == nil) {
    let nib: NSArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProductListCell", owner: self, options: nil)! as NSArray
    cell = (nib.object(at: 0) as? ProductListCell)!
}
```

`
Use the below code in viewDidLoad

```
 self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "ProductListCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProductListCell")
```

If the issue is still occuring use the below library for image caching
[Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

it is a lightweight library with less memory impact

Comment: func setView() {
     
        
        self.clvProducts.register(UINib(nibName: "ProductListCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProductListCell")
        
        self.clvProducts.register(UINib(nibName: "ProductGridCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProductGridCell")
     
    
    }

Comment: I did that thing

Comment: I would suggest you to use kingfisher library for image download

Comment: but the best way is after scrolling collection view only we can get data

Comment: If you use kingfisher it will take care of the rest.It will update the image automatically Without causing any memory issues.Even if you scroll fast it wont download the image multiple times

Comment: by using kingfisher then also same thing

Comment: yah bro, iam following same procedure

Comment: Not related to the issue .But by looking at your code i could see a lot of dangerous coding 
eg self.objCategorywiseResponse.SimilirProductsList![indexPath.row]
why it this code is repeated and you are force unwrapping the array.
In the first line assign  this object to a variable and and use that variable in the rest of your code